# Context manager: Error handling inside __init__ method

Tags: python, contextmanager

**A bit of context**

I am working with a package that allows you to calculate several things about planets (such as their speed, or position), using information stored in files. The package includes methods to load, and unload files, so its basic usage would look like this:

```py
load(["File_1", "File_2"])

try:

    function()

finally:

    unload(["File_1", "File_2"])
```

As this is a textbook example of the utility of a context manager, and the package lacks one, I am writing my own.

```py
class file_manager:

    def __init__(self, file_list) -> None:

        self.file_list = file_list

        load(self.file_list)

        return None

    def __enter__(self) -> None:

        return None

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback) -> None:

        unload(self.file_list)

        return None
```

With the new context manager, the previous example can be rewritten as follows:

```py
with file_manager(["File_1", "File_2"]):

    function()
```

and the `__exit__` method guarantees that files will still be unloaded if `function` raises an error.

**My problem**

The `load` function loads files one by one, without first checking if all of them are available. As a result, if `File_1` exists, but `File_2` doesn't, `File_1` will be loaded, and an exception will be raised while loading `File_2`. According to python documentation:

> The with statement guarantees that if the `__enter__()` method returns without an error, then `__exit__()` will always be called.

Therefore, in the previous case, the execution of the program will end without `File_2` being unloaded.

**What am I looking for**

I can obviously fix this by using a `try...except` clause inside the `__init__()` method:

```py
def __init__(self, file_list) -> None:

    self.file_list = file_list

    try:

        load(self.file_list)

    except FileDoesNotExistError:

        self.__exit__(FileDoesNotExistError, False, None)
```

but I want to know if this is the proper way to solve this problem. For example, in Cython, classes have a `__dealloc__()` method, which is guaranteed to run, no matter what type of exception occurs.

Comment: That is not a textbook example (unless you're reading the wrong textbook). \_\_enter__ needs to return *self*

Comment: @Cobra I'm sorry, I didn't mean that. I ment that one obvious reason to use context managers is to avoid having to close files manually.

Comment: @Cobra, `__enter__` doesn't need to return self if there isn't anything that needs to be accessed from inside the context.

Comment: What would be the preferred behaviour if the *load()* function raises an exception?

Comment: @Holloway I said nothing about calling *self*

Comment: @Cobra, sorry typo. It doesn't need to return self either.

Comment: @Holloway You're right in saying that it doesn't **have** to. But you have to bear in mind that someone else in your team may want to use this class and keep a reference to it. Therefore, returning self fits with the signature of that function and makes it more robust

Comment: The call to `load` should probably be in `__enter__`, not `__init__`.

Comment: @Cobra It depends entirely on the use case. There are plenty of context managers that do not return `self`. `__enter__` should return what is *useful*. If it has nothing useful to return, `None` is fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can wrap your original code using [`contextlib.contextmanager`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.contextmanager).

```py
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def file_manager(file_list):
    try:
        load(file_list)
        yield None  # after this the code inside the with block is executed 
    finally:
        # this is called when the with block has finished
        # or when load raises an exception
        unload(file_list)
```

and use it like

```py
with file_manager(["File_1", "File_2"]):
    function()
```

Comment: Worth pointing out: when you call `file_manager`, nothing happens except to create a context manager. No code in the body of the function executes when you write `fm = file_manager(some_list_of_files)`. Only once `fm.__enter__` is called does the body of the function begin to execute; everything before `yield` constitutes the `__enter__` method, and everything after it the `__exit__` method. (This is, in part, why I suggested in a comment to the question that the call to `load` should be in `__enter__`, not `__init__`.